# Can't perform correct openGL ES panning

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I'm trying to create an openGL ES object panning, and i'm using the following method's to do that:

First, the render method:

```
- (void)render:(CADisplayLink*)displayLink {
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    CC3GLMatrix *projection = [CC3GLMatrix matrix];
    float h = 4.0f * self.frame.size.height / self.frame.size.width;
    [projection populateFromFrustumLeft:-2 andRight:2 andBottom:-h/2 andTop:h/2 andNear:4 andFar:100];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_projectionUniform, 1, 0, projection.glMatrix);

    // This is where the panning is being done
    [modelView populateFromTranslation:_currentPan];
    _currentRotation += displayLink.duration * 50;
    [modelView rotateBy:CC3VectorMake(0, 0, 0)];
    glUniformMatrix4fv(_modelViewUniform, 1, 0, modelView.glMatrix);

    glViewport(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height);

    glVertexAttribPointer(_positionSlot, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), 0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(_colorSlot, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float)* 3));
    glVertexAttribPointer(_texCoordSlot, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE,
                          sizeof(Vertex), (GLvoid*) (sizeof(float) * 7));


    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, _floorTexture);
    glUniform1i(_textureUniform, 0);


    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, numberOfFaces*3, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);

    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}
```

And the translation function:

```
- (void) translateXAxis:(float)x andY:(float)y
{
    float dx = translationEnd.x + (x-translationStart.x);
    float dy = translationEnd.y - (y-translationStart.y);
    translationEnd.x = dx;
    translationEnd.y = dy;
    translationStart.x = x;
    translationStart.y = y;
    _currentPan = CC3VectorMake(-translationEnd.x*depthFactor, -translationEnd.y*depthFactor, depthFactor);
}
```

Everything works fine and the object is moving as it should except the case i'm dragging the object to a certain location on screen, placing the mouse curser in a different location (currently testing it on the iOS simulator) and start dragging it again.

In the mentioned scenario, the model just jumps right back to the middle where it started, and resumes the panning from there. i really am trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize `_currentPan` to zero at the start of every new gesture.

Comment: yeah i thought about it also, but it only sums up the panning, meaning, it doesn't jump to the beginning again, but each phase in the panning is the sum of the previous panning's which make's the model jump in large amounts

Comment: do you initialize translationStart when you start the gesture? It should be reinitialized to zero.

Comment: Yeah i have... it is initialised to zero. the thing is, once the translateXAxis:andY: is being called again, the x and y values initialise to zero and start the panning again, from these new x and y values, this what causes the jumps, still trying to solve this...

Comment: If you are not re-initializing _currentPan then I don't understand why it would jump back to zero. As far as I can tell from your code _currentPan is the pan applied. The only reason it would jump back to zero is if _currentPan jumped back to zero. Maybe log _currentPan and see where it is getting set to zero?

Comment: Well, it turns out you were right, but so was i :) my calculation were correct, but i really had to initialise _currentPan on every NEW gesture started, so if you can re-edit your'e answer i would happily except it. Thanks man!